# .prepend() result is visible to everybody not only to the person making the action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the .prepend() action into a page when a user click on a button.

I think only the clicker can see the element being added into the list but what do for all the users already watching this page can also see it ?

PS : A good example is the friend news thread of facebook (in the right column) where one actuality appears for everybody.

Comment: @rlemon - God I HOPE so. The thought that this person might be a professional web developer is much more frightening.

Answer (score 0):

DOM operations are purely in YOUR browser. Unless your JS code pings the server with an update on the actions, and your server pushes that data to any observers, there's no way for one user's browser to 'spy' on what another's is doing.

Answer (score 0):

When you say other users, do you mean other users of the site?

If so then the answer is no. Only that user will see ANY change made to the DOM in javascript because the change is only happening on the local computer. This is true regardless of whether AJAX is used.

Here's a metaphor to help you understand. When a web site gives a user a page, it is like mailing a letter to that user. The person who receives the letter (html document) can make changes all day long and it won't affect anyone else who got a copy of that letter.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand jQuery prepend(). It does not perform any AJAX. It will simply insert new HTML on the page. If it is passed an existing HTML element, it will move that element to the beginning of element that you are prepending to.

For example:

```
// this adds a new paragraph to the beginning of the main content div
$('#mainContentDiv').prepend('<p>New content</p>');
```

See the jQuery API for more info: [jQuery .prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Notice you will not find AJAX mentioned anywhere on the page except in a comment by Karl Swedberg, and he refers to the AJAX docs.

You will probably need to use something like jQuery.ajax() separate from .prepend() to make the server update for other users to receive the change.